# GOOGLE SLIDES: Prevent User From Moving To The Next Slide Using The Keyboard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a very **simple** presentation that I created using **Google Slides** and I published it as a website (**Publish To The Web**). The link is below.

What I want is to **prevent the user** from navigating the slides (moving to the next slide or previous slide) **using the keyboard**. I want to force him **only** to click on the Next Slide / Previous Slide buttons that I created on the slide.

Appreciate your help

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vQMQdpDXHl2rVIk6dkj8tEcTKYhcBOlW9v-TkCGuggutriEztCrEoI9c9Eazv4_hiufvKeGPa9A4zY4/pub?rm=minimal

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to an answer from a similar post [A Google script to disable keys in a keyboard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124326), Google Apps Script can't disable keys in a keyboard nor includes any service to modify the key behavior in Google Slides or any other Google services.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late but I'm pretty sure you just have to right click on the slide and click on skip slide.